# Does a priority queue exist with O(1) extract-min and re-insertion from removed positions?

Tags: data-structures, priority-queues, tree-traversal

I am envisioning a priority queue that is a bit strange. It represents wanting to do a depth-first left-to-right walk of a tree, but allowing for parallel workers where there can be time between assigning a node to a worker and getting new child nodes back to explore, leaving the depth-first left-to-right property as a best effort.

The priority queue $Q$ is always initialized with a single element $r$. Then we have two operations:

1. $\texttt{extract-min}(Q)$ finds the least element $x \in Q$, removes it from the data structure and returns it to us, along with an arbitrary handle $h_x$ that represents the removal of $x$.
2. $\texttt{re-insert}(Q, h_x, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ inserts prioritized elements $a_1 <  a_2 <  \dots < a_n$ into the data structure such that for any $l \in Q$ where $l < x$ we have $l < a_1$ and for any $g \in Q$ where $x < g$ we have $a_n < g$. Here $a < b$ means that $a$ is prioritized before $b$ (and will thus be extracted earlier). This consumes handle $h_x$, thus not allowing multiple re-insertions.

Note that the priorities are entirely lexicographically determined by the re-insertions, at no point do we actually compare any objects (the elements of the priority can be arbitrary objects which may not be comparable or have observable properties at all). Essentially our priority queue represents a tree $T$ where after starting with a single unpainted root node $r$:

1. $\texttt{extract-min}(T)$ finds the first unpainted leaf node $x$ in the pre-order left-to-right traversal and paints it with a unique color $h_x$.
2. $\texttt{re-insert}(T, h_x,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ adds new leaves $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ (listed in left-to-right order) as children to the node $x$ painted with color $h_x$. Node $x$ is now painted black so it may never have children added again.

##### Is it possible to implement both operations in $O(1)$?

---

Important note: $\texttt{extract-min}$ may be called an arbitrary number of times before a $\texttt{re-insert}$ with an old handle happens. However each handle may only be used once.

Comment: For starters, if we start with only one element, won't this mean that we always have at most one handle to use? Also, in the $re-insert$ operation: if $l<x\implies l<a_1$ and $r>x\implies  r>a_n>a_1$, then won't this mean that $a_1=x$ (and thus also $n=1$ always)?

Comment: @nirshahar We start with one element, $r$ but then I could, say, re-insert 5 elements after removing $r$, using the handle $h_r$. The priority relation between $a_i$ and $x$ when $a_i$ is re-inserted using handle $h_x$ is irrelevant because they will never be in the priority queue simultaneously. However I've been sloppy and accidentally re-used the symbol $r$ for both the initial element and "elements to the right". Let me fix that.

Comment: Doesn't the same argument still apply? My point is that if $\forall m,M: m<x<M\implies m<a_1<M$, then doesn't that mean that $x=a_1$ (since otherwise, for example, if $a_1>x$, we could choose $ M=\frac{a_1+x}{2}>x $ but $a_1>M$)

Comment: @nirshahar It's a partially ordered set. There is no defined order between an element $x$ and the sequence of elements $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ that replaces it. All that section is saying that if something was ordered before $x$, it will still be ordered before the elements that replaced $x$, and vice versa for objects that were ordered after $x$. In particular, the objects in question are *not* numbers or integers.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that $l,g,x\in Q$ (for the $re-insert$ part)? Or am I missing anything

Comment: And finally when I say "for all $l < x$ or all $x < g$" I only mean to make a statement about how objects are prioritized in the queue. The ordering outside of the priority queue is meaningless and non-existent. So yes, $l, g \in Q$. Allow me to clarify that in the question by adding it in.

Comment: Also - one last thing. Do you ever get rid of elements totally (*both* element and the handle)? Because otherwise the memory usage will depend on the number of inserts, and not on the actual number of elements currently in $Q$. Basically what I'm asking is whether a removal will always actually remove the element, or just convert it to some "handle" (and render the element 'useless')

Comment: @nirshahar The idea is to eventually consume those things that don't expand anymore. That is easy to keep track of with a doubly linked list, since each re-insertion can be implemented as simply inserting the elements ($a_1, \dots, a_n$) after (for pre-order, or before for post-order) the parent $x$ in this linked list using the parent handle $h_x$, and then marking the parent $x$ as done. Then as long as the head of the linked list is marked as done, we can output it (producing an ordered traversal of our tree), and reclaim the memory for that node.

Comment: @nirshahar If a node is found to have no children I will likely simply call `reinsert` with $n = 0$ for consistency so everything gets marked and cleaned up using the same algorithm.